# Dgrid selection mix-in issue with order

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I've been having issues with the dgrid selection mix-in with multi selects.

Using the selection property (for example)

```
var selected = Object.keys(datatable.selection)
```

it returns an array of row ids as expected. However the ORDER of those ids seems to be "arbitrary". It seems perhaps that the order of selecting has an affect.

In any event, in the datatable, I want the selected rows to be returned in order that they display in the list, and they do not.

I can get them in the proper order using `dojo.query(".dgrid-selected", datatable.domNode)`, and use the HTML element to get the row data, but this seems like a hack.

I cannot find a proper method to do this on the SitePen docs. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a direct way to do that. The `Object.keys(datatable.selection)` returns the array of ids in the order in which the rows are selected. You can use some built-in functions of `d-grid` and JS to achieve this. Below are the steps:

1. Get the id by `Object.keys`.

   `var selected = Object.keys(datatable.selection)`
2. Create a list of objects comprising of id and `rowIndex` of element

Code:

```
var dataList= [];
for(var i=0; i< selected.length; i++){
    dataList.push({id: selected[i], index: datatable.row(selected[i]).element.rowIndex});
}
```

3. Sort the list using `index` as the attribute:

`dataList.sort(function(a, b){ return a.index- b.index; })`

The resulting `dataList` would have the list of objects in order in which they appear in the grid.

Comment: thanks. Worked great. My other method, using the dom object worked too, but I really thought it was more of a hack.

Comment: @DanPiccolo: Glad I could help. Yeah, using DOM seems more like a hack to me also. I also tend to use in-built methods provided by `d-grid`.

Comment: @Himanshu: What if after selecting some rows in first page, I hit sort on the column. As a result of which the selected row goes to some other page in the grid. element will become null in that case and thus selected[i]).element.rowIndex won't work. How do I get the correct index in that case ?

Comment: @Vicky: I think the convention to follow here is that when data is sorted or page is changed, then the selection should get cleared automatically. By doing this, the user will have to select the rows again and you can get the `element` and `rowIndex` properly.